# Range not found when i use getRange(atr)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

how to correct refer on range object with custom function in apps script, using atribute? how to getRange()  get reference on Range??

```
function A1(cell){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  val = sheet.getRange(cell).getValue();
  
  return val;
};
```

Comment: could you tell us what is the value of cell when you are calling this function ?

Comment: Hi ! How are you passing the argument ```cell``` into your function? Could you please provide an example of ```cell```? Is it a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can place `var` in front of `val`
Here is the corrected script:

```
function A1(cell){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var val = sheet.getRange(cell).getValue();
  
  return val;
};
```

**Also, make sure when using the function, that `cell` is wrapped in quotes for it to work**
`=A1("D4")`

Comment: missing var is not an issue at all. He is just using wrong arguments for his function.

Comment: My bad, ive just always done them separately. In that case, I don't see anything wrong with it. It works fine for me. Is there something im missing?

Comment: Your answer is fine :) he must be passing to his function wrong arguments.